# aws cloudformation "NetworkInterfaces" in Autoscaling launchconfig group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In aws cloudformation how to add "NetworkInterfaces" in Autoscaling launchconfig group as I want to configure every instance launched and I need "NetworkInterfaces" to be there same AWS::EC2::Instance?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was curious if I need to add network interface to every instance launched in autoscaling group. But later discovered that I wouldn't need to. Thanks for reply, Edwin.

Comment: @Edwin The scenario occurs when you want the singleton member of the ASG to restart with the same Network Interface.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm currently using is to ensure that every Instance is launched with an [IAM Instance Profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-instanceprofile.html) that allows contains the Policy

```json
"PolicyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Cloud Formation Template for creating the [AutoScalingGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html) and [LaunchConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html) receives Parameters for [Subnets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html) and [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html) to attach to each additional [ENI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html).

```json
"SecondaryNICSubnetIds":{
    "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
    "Description" : "Ensure that the spread of Availability Zones for these Subnets matches the SubnetIds used to create Instances, as when creating a Secondary ENI it must exist in the same AZ as the Instance"
},
"SecondaryNICSecurityGroupIds":{
    "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
    "Description" : "Security Groups to associate to the Secondary ENI"
},
```

Then the [LaunchConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html) contains a [UserData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) property that

1. ensures awscli is installed
2. sets the region to use by parse the [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) identity document
3. gets the instance id from the [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval)
4. gets the availability zone for the instance from the [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval)
5. from the Subnets that have been passed in find the first that matches my instances AZ by using the [awscli describe-subnets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-subnets.html) call
6. Creates a Network Interface in my chosen Subnet, and add Security Groups to it using the [awscli create-network-interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-network-interface.html) call
7. Tag my [ENI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html) using the [awscli create-tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html) call
8. Attach [ENI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html) to my Instance using the [awscli attach-network-interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/attach-network-interface.html) call
9. Modify Attachment to Delete the [ENI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html) on Instance Termination using the [modify-network-interface-attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-network-interface-attribute.html) call

```json
"UserData": {
      "Fn::Base64" : {
        "Fn::Join": [ "\n",
          [
            "#!/bin/bash -xe",
            "sudo apt-get install -y awscli",
            "export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$(curl -sS http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[\"region\"])')",
            "INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -sS http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)",
            "AZ=$(curl -sS http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)",
            "echo Availability Zone: ${AZ}",
            {"Fn::Sub":[
                "SUBNET_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-subnets --subnet-ids ${SubnetNetIds} --filters Name=availabilityZone,Values=${!AZ} --query 'Subnets[0].SubnetId' --output text)",
                {"SubnetNetIds":  {"Fn::Join": [" ", {"Ref": "SecondaryNICSubnetIds"} ] }}
            ]},
            "echo Subnet Id: ${SUBNET_ID}",
            {"Fn::Sub":[
              "ENI_ID=$(aws ec2 create-network-interface --subnet ${!SUBNET_ID} --description 'Secondary ENI' --groups ${SecurityGroups} --query 'NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceId' --output text)",
              {"SecurityGroups":  {"Fn::Join": [" ", {"Ref": "SecondaryNICSecurityGroupIds"}]} }
            ]},
            "echo ENI ID: ${ENI_ID}",
            "aws ec2 create-tags --resources ${!ENI_ID} --tags Key=Some,Value=Tag",
            "ATTACHMENT_ID=$(aws ec2 attach-network-interface --network-interface-id ${ENI_ID} --instance-id ${INSTANCE_ID} --device-index 1 --output text)",
            "echo Attachment ID: ${ATTACHMENT_ID}",
            "echo Delete On Termination: $(aws ec2 modify-network-interface-attribute --network-interface-id ${ENI_ID} --attachment AttachmentId=${ATTACHMENT_ID},DeleteOnTermination=true --output text)"
           ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

If you didn't want to pass the [Subnets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html) into the Cloud Formation Template you could attempt to look them up by adding tags to `--query` in the [awscli describe-subnets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-subnets.html) call, if your infrastructure allows you to identify them this way.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach need Access Key ID and Secret Access Key to execute the "aws ec2 attach-network-interface" command within the EC2 instance?

Comment: If you were using an IAM instance profile then these are not required to be hosted in an EC2 instance - the identity management and authorisation is handled by Ec2 and IAM