# How to assign a static Private IP's to AWS EC2 instances in an AutoScalingGroup for High Availability via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I have a cloud formation pipeline that builds an AutoScalingGroup in AWS and deploys a couple of EC2 instances in High Availability to run an application service on. The problem is that when I push an update through the pipeline the existing nodes are terminated and swapped out for the new updates in a blue/green deployment style creating new EC2 instances with new Instance ID's and new IP's

How can I ensure that when node 1 is terminated and replaced with the updated node 1 that the updated node will have the same private IPv4 as the one before it?

I have tried with AWS EIP and ENI and I cant find a way that works since each node has a different subnet ID and Availability Zone.

These are two options I have found so far:

1. https://binx.io/blog/2019/09/10/how-to-dynamically-bind-static-private-ip-addresses-to-an-auto-scaling-group/
2. [aws cloudformation "NetworkInterfaces" in Autoscaling launchconfig group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836854/aws-cloudformation-networkinterfaces-in-autoscaling-launchconfig-group)

Option 1 wont work for me as it mentions the autoscaling group should be bound to a single AZ which is not my use case.

I dont understand what option 2 is doing or how to implement it and so I have not been able to try it.

The one idea I had was to create an ENI within the cloudformation script for each node that will be spun up and attach it based on Instance ID of the node spun up. But I do not know if that will work or how to achieve it since I will need to reference the SubnetID and InstanceID of each node as its created to then attach the ENI correctly

Comment: Why do you need the IPs to stay the same? How are you connecting to these servers? Do you not have a load balancer in front of them? There is probably a different method in AWS to handle your scenario, if you could explain the core problem.

Comment: I need the IP's to stay the same as I need to connect to the service with a tcp connection directly to each node in the ASG

Comment: If you're doing an actual blue/green deployment, I don't see how it's going to be possible to maintain the IPs. Aren't both the old and new servers running simultaneously at some point during the deployment? I would try to look into maintaining DNS records that are updated to point to the latest servers, instead of relying on the IP directly.  Something like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/blue-green-deployments/update-dns-routing-with-amazon-route-53.html Or maybe look into using AWS Cloud Map. Otherwise, maybe think about updating servers instead of replacing them.

Comment: So what happens is node 1 is terminated before being replaced with the updated node 1. During this time node 2 is still active. Is it not possible for me to then, for example, have an ENI thats attached to node 1 get detached when node 1 is bought down and reattached when updated node 1 is brought back up since the ENI is free to be attached to the new instance?

Comment: When you say "when updated node 1 is brought back up" it makes me think that you have a misunderstanding of how auto-scaling groups work. There is no "updated node 1", there's a _completely new_ EC2 instance.

Comment: And I'll repeat Mark B's question: _what is the core problem?_ The fact that something tries to connect to the node via TCP is how you chose to solve that problem, it's not the problem itself.

Comment: @Parsifal I understand how ASG works. In this case there are 2 nodes. Node 1 and 2 are what I am using to refer to the EC2 instances. I get that Node 1, once updated and replaced is a completely new node. But that doesnt change the fact that it is node 1, hence, "brought back up". Either way I think you are focusing on a poor choice of wording on my part rather than the question.
The TCP connection is needed to send a byte stream payload and cannot be done any other way. So the core problem is that I need to find a way to allow for new instances in the ASG to assume the same IP's of the old.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to maintain a pool of IP addresses and leverage support for [multiple IP addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html). I haven't done this, and consider it a brittle solution, so not an answer. (I have done something similar for Elastic IPs, which is why I consider it brittle)

Comment: @Jefledge are you sure you can't do this with a network load balancer? Why does the bytestream have to go to a specific server?

Comment: Unfortunately the sending system cannot use a pool of IP's, it needs a set of two static IP's with specific ports. As I understand for the NLB as well is that they will connect to it via a DNS which again wont work since they need the direct IP

Comment: Network load balancers have static IPs. It sounds like Network Load Balancers would work perfectly for you. From the documentation: "Network Load Balancer automatically provides a static IP per Availability Zone (subnet) that can be used by applications as the front-end IP of the load balancer. Network Load Balancer also allows you the option to assign an Elastic IP per Availability Zone (subnet) thereby providing your own fixed IP."

Comment: I looked into this and apparently I wont be able to implement the NLB option as it wont keep the TCP session open. However I did find a working solution that is similar to the one link I shared above in my question

Comment: @Jefledge Could you please share your solutions for it?